# Is my EC2 in a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Is there a definitive way to tell if an EC2 instance is in a VPC or not?

When I look at the description of the instance, I see this:

[image: Empty VPC ID]

When I look at my VPC (which I didn't know I had), I see this:

[image: Dashboard summary]

and the EC2 instance that I looked at above is one of the '2 Runnning Instaces'.

So why does the EC2 instance not have a VPC ID?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking at a wrong instance or your instance is in `EC2 Classic`.

EC2-VPC instance will have `VPC ID` and `Subnet ID` attributes, the EC2-Classic one will not have it.

If you are using the dashboard, look for `VPC ID` or `Subnet ID` attribute. If using SDK/API, the VPC instances will have `vpc_id` and `subnet_id` attributes defined.